# An additional background at bottom of page

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap to create my personal webpage, and i tried to add a gradient background to `<body>` but i ended up with a meaningless space of gradient there. Here is images, i can't include jsfiddle because i have more than one CSS files.

http://jsfiddle.net/eJ3CL/

You can't see the problem in jsfiddle since bootstrap is not included there, but here are the screenshots:

**EDIT:**
Edited [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eJ3CL/2/) to include bootstrap and set height of content middle to 120px so that others can see the problem that OP wants to convey.

[image: when I set container height to 900]

[image: when I set container height to 500]

What is causing this? How can I fix this problem?

Edited: Here is all the relevant code.

```
<head>
    <title>Burak Özmen - A Newbie Designer</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />  
    <link href="css/reset.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

</head>
<body>
    <div class="container container-top">
        <div class="page-header">
            <h1>Burak Özmen <small>A Newbie Developer</small></h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container container-middle">
        <div class="navbar navbar-static-top navbar-inverse">
            <div class="navbar-inner">
                <ul class="nav">
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About Me</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="pull-right">Link</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="vertical-middle">In development... </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

style.css:

```
body {
background: rgb(249,252,247); /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(249,252,247,1) 0%, rgba(245,249,240,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(249,252,247,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(245,249,240,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(249,252,247,1) 0%,rgba(245,249,240,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(249,252,247,1) 0%,rgba(245,249,240,1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(249,252,247,1) 0%,rgba(245,249,240,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(249,252,247,1) 0%,rgba(245,249,240,1) 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#f9fcf7', endColorstr='#f5f9f0',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */


}

.container-middle {
    height: 300px;
    background: white;

}
```

Comment: What is "a meaningless space of gradient" ?

Comment: I couldn't express it with words so I uploaded images to show what is it. Sorry for inadequate language there.

Comment: We can't help you if you can't explain your problem.

Comment: Post *all* of your relevant code

Comment: I thought I was clear with the images i provided.

Comment: I posted HTML and CSS code, even though i included them in jsfiddle.

Comment: First try to set quirksmode off with <!DOCTYPE html> before html-element.

Comment: It is included in original file. I think I forgot to copy that line.

Comment: without a working jsFiddle, it is hard to help you.

Comment: I tried it, and it is not observable in jsfiddle. I should delete this question then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give a min-height to body

```
body {
  min-height: 400px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

move the rules in body selector to html selector and add `height:100%;` rule to `html` selector.

```
html{
background: rgb(249,252,247); /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(249,252,247,1) 0%, rgba(245,249,240,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(249,252,247,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(245,249,240,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(249,252,247,1) 0%,rgba(245,249,240,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(249,252,247,1) 0%,rgba(245,249,240,1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(249,252,247,1) 0%,rgba(245,249,240,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(249,252,247,1) 0%,rgba(245,249,240,1) 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#f9fcf7', endColorstr='#f5f9f0',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
height: 100%;

}

.container-middle {
    height: 300px;
    background: white;

}
```

It works on Firefox, Chrome and IE9

Comment: Did you change body to html? What browser do you use?

Comment: I use Google Chrome and yes, i did.